# Why am I getting "TypeError: Assignment to constant variable" when trying to import my function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to import my function from `utils/login.js` file, in my `login.js` file I have this.

```
login = (usern, passw) => {
  try {
    // do something
  } catch (error) {
    return(error)
  }
};

module.exports.login;
```

I also have a `utils/index.js` file with this in

```
module.exports = {
    login: require("./login")
}
```

when I run `const {login} = require("./utils")` from the terminal I get this error but I'm not sure how to resolve it

`TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests, seems like the constant `login` was already declared in your scope.

You have to rename the constant.